# Javascript codecademy 5.5 function doesn't return correct data

Tags: javascript

Thanks for having a look at my question! I'm trying to complete the JavaScript course in codecademy and this has me stumped. I can't even find help in the codecademy forums. I am trying to figure out why "Bob Jones" isn't logged to the console. Any help is greatly appreciated. Here is my code:

```
var bob = {
    firstName: "Bob",
    lastName: "Jones",
    phoneNumber: "(650) 777-7777",
    email: "bob.jones@example.com"
};

var mary = {
    firstName: "Mary",
    lastName: "Johnson",
    phoneNumber: "(650) 888-8888",
    email: "mary.johnson@example.com"
};

var contacts = [bob, mary];

function printPerson(person) {
    console.log(person.firstName + " " + person.lastName);
};

function list() {
    var contactsLength = contacts.length;
    for (var i = 0; i < contactsLength; i++) {
        printPerson(contacts[i]);
    }
};

/*Create a search function
then call it passing "Jones"*/
function search(lastName){
    var contactsLength = contacts.Length;
    for(var i = 0; i<contactsLength; i++){
        if(lastName === contacts[i].lastName){
            printPerson(contacts[i]);
        }
    }
};
search("Jones");
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that JavaScript is case sensitive and the array length is available under the `length`property, not `Length`.

P.S. learn to use a debugger.

Comment: Thank you so much Amit! Downloading firebug as I type this comment. I really appreciate your help.

Comment: @JenKutler: if this answer solved your problem, please remember to mak it as accepted by clicking on the tick icon on its left. Thank you!